# Magento - Customer Login Page Change

Tags: php, css, magento

I am working on magento and new for magento i use lots of templates now i am working on Magento Classic Theme , i google it alot lots of person says changes possible in base default i will go there and login.phtml file remove code when i refresh on template there is nothing to gone everything will be same

**C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form**

then i will try to workin on main templates files in main template folder but still there is no change now i am totally confuse how to fix this problem and how to edit the customer login page as per own choice

**C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\default\f002\template**

I need a suggestions and guide from you please help me out in this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\login.phtml`

Not the one in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form`

And always look into path by enabling Template Path Hints

1. Open the admin control panel
2. Open the system tab and select configuration
3. Select Main Website or Name of your website (NOT DEFAULT CONFIG) from the Current Configuration Scope drop down
4. Select Developer on the left sidebar
5. Open the Debug drop down
6. Set Template Path Hints To Yes
7. Click on Save Config to save down your changes